# Building an Ember App on localhost with the API built in Vagrant

Tags: javascript, ember.js, vagrant, localhost

I have previously built Ember apps on a vagrant box and have had to deal with build times which are 5+ minutes. I was able to reduce this time significantly by building on my localhost. The problem is the back-end developers I work with have built the API within vagrant so it looks like the only way I can connect to the API is by developing within vagrant.

I've made attempts to connect to the API by using the ember s --proxy [domain on vagrant box] function but this hasn't worked. The API is still being developed so it is not hosted on a live domain just yet - just a development environment.

Is there a way I can connect to the API within vagrant but still develop on my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, you just need to forward the port that your API is running on from your Vagrant machine.

i.e. `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888`

Where "guest" port in the port on you Vagrant machine, and the "host" is the port you will be targeting from ember.